# CSS Border Not Apprearing on Div

Tags: html, css, border

I am making a page for my website which has a navigation link class called `.link` that is put on some `div`s. When I apply a border on it, it does not show. The same border (except border's radius and width) is applied to another `div` called `#pageHead` and shows properly. In the following code, only the parts that are relevant are shown. The link to the stylesheet is in the head of the document and I know it works properly. The HTML is inside of `body` tags and everything is inside of `html` tags and headed with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

In my HTML:

```
<div id="pageHead">
    <h1>CodeGameCentral</h1>
    <h3>Games Made With Code</h3>
</div>
<div id="links">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="../main/?pageNumber=1">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS:

```
#pageHead{
    background-color:#7F7F7F;
    border:3px solid #FF0000;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top:none;
    color:#AA0000;
}
    h1, h3, #links{
        font-family:monsopace;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #links{
        width:90%;
        margin:auto;
    }
        .link{
            background-color:#7F7F7F;
            border:2px solid #7F7F7F;
            border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
            border-top:none;
            cursor:pointer;
            text-align:center;
            width:100%;
        }
            a{
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#AA0000;
            }
```

Putting these excerpts inside of appropriate tags within an HTML editor will replicate the result. I used htmledit.squarefree.com to test that, and put the code like this.

```
<head>
<style>
<!--The CSS excerpt above-->
</style>
<body>
<!--The HTML excerpt above-->
</body>
```

Here is a screenshot. The box with 'Home' in it should have a border, but doesn't.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epcop.jpg

For clarity, I am trying to find out how to fix `.link`'s border and, if you know, why this happened.

Comment: what is that does not work? it seems fine on this [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ov4ewhxf/).

Comment: Thanks! Through yours and other comments I realized my mistake - the background and border were the same color... I feel like I wasted some peoples' time here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .link{
        background-color:#7F7F7F;
        border:2px solid #7F7F7F; /* Change the Color Code to see the difference */
        border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
        border-top:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
```

The `border` and `background-color` are same. Give the different color to see the border for `.link`

Here is a **[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/dv1Lceqn/)**

Comment: Thanks! Through yours and other comments I realized my mistake - the background and border were the same color... I feel like I wasted some peoples' time here...

Comment: It's ok. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

same color for `background` and `border` caused the issue

so change `border-color`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqd1qyhv/)

```
  .link{
            background-color:#7F7F7F;
            border:2px solid Blue;
            border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
            border-top:none;
            cursor:pointer;
            text-align:center;
            width:100%;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Through yours and other comments I realized my mistake - the background and border were the same color... I feel like I wasted some peoples' time here...